# My method doesn't work and doesn't return an array

Tags: php, arrays, oop, object, methods

I have a method called **getPerso** which return an array with all the information of my member. Here is the method :

```
public function getPerso($id)
{
    if(is_int($id))
    {
        $req = $this->_db->prepare('SELECT * FROM personnages WHERE id = :id');
        $req->execute(array(
            'id' => $id));
        $donnee = $req->fetch();
        $req->closeCursor();
        return $donnee;
    }
}
```

It only needs an int as parameter. I use `$_SESSION['id']` which contains the id of the member logged in for the parameter. But, when I execute this code :

```
$donnee = $manager->getPerso($_SESSION['id']);
var_dump($donnee, $_SESSION['id']);
```

My $donnee variable is empty. Here's what I get from the var_dump :

> NULL string(1) "4"

My $donnee variable is supposed to contain an array with all the information of the member. Hope someone has a solution.

Comment: Either there is no matching row for `:id`, or you are not seeing an error. By default, PDO errors silently. Have you setup the connection to throw exceptions?  `$this->_db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` will ensure it will throw an exception if the `prepare()` fails. Otherwise, you just might not have a matching row.

Comment: you're simply assuming your query succeeded. unless you explicitly enable exceptions, PDO returns boolean false on failure. So either your ->prepare failed, the ->execute() failed, or the ->fetch() failed.

Comment: `$req->execute(array(':id' => $id));`

Comment: You might want to use is_numeric() instead of is_int(). is_int() will return false if you are passing a number as a string.

Comment: @Billy That should be an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use is_numeric() instead of is_int(). is_int() will return false if you are passing a number as a string